# Get multiple substrings from string

Tags: c#, html, string, substring

So I have html files. I need to extract all the links and images from them. So basically I need:

`<a href="this_is_what_I_need">` and `<img src="this_is_also_needed">`

I read the files line-by-line and can get it, but only the first one:

```
    List<string> links = new List<string>();
    if (line.Contains(@"<a href=""") || line.Contains(@"<img src="""))
    {
        if (line.Contains(@"<a href=""")
        {
            links.Add(line.Split(new string[] { @"<a href""" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('"')[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            links.Add(line.Split(new string[] { @"<a href=""" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('"')[0]);
        }
    }
```

But a line might contain multiple links and/or images. So how to get all?

Comment: First of all, it would be nice to know what kind of variable line is.
second of all, it seems to me that you need a while loop, until the end of file is reached.
While (!EOF)

Comment: Use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Please use a tool like the HTML Agility Pack instead - just search for all "a" or "img" elements, and fetch the "@href" attribute.

Comment: Something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will be better than direct string manipulation for this kind of task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I  don't think that you are using the right approach for doing that  what I can suggest is to take a look at a scrapping tool  like  [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) which it is optimized for doing such things

here  an example for doing that with `<a href=""` but you can adapt it for `<img src="""`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("mytest.htm");

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='dn-index-link']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("node:" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
}
```

Comment: Also is this work for php files as well?

Comment: @fishmong3r No this is for C#, .NET. PHP has it's own tools/extensions/classes to handle this

Comment: @fishmong3r if you mean the *input* is php; you'll have to try it to see what HTML Agility Pack does with it

Comment: Yeah, of course I mean the input is php.

Comment: If there is no a href in a file the prog dies. How to check it first like `if(there is no node) return;`

Comment: never mind, I solved it with try-catch combo. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @fishmong3r alternately, you could break the foreach loop out --  
    `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='dn-index-link']"));`  
then check nodes and return, if necessary.